# File used by another process when using file html element

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file

I am developing a file upload popup which uses the Azure blob storage. The "meat" of the popup looks like this

```
<div id="bookmarkFileSelector" style="display: none">
    <div>
       <div class="demo-section">
          <div id="bookmarkListView"></div>
          <div id="bookmarkPager" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>
       </div>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="">Select</button>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="uploadFilesButton" ng-click="openFileDialog()">Upload</button>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
               ng-disabled="isBookmarkSelected == false" id="deleteFileButton"
               ng-click="deleteFile()" style="margin-left: 20px">Delete</button>

       <div id="uploadFiles" >
          <input type="file" id="selectedFile" />
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click the `Upload` button I call this function

```
$scope.openFileDialog = function () {
    $('#selectedFile').focus();
    $('#selectedFile').click();
};
```

This way I open the file dialog but don't have to use the default layout but my (bootstrapped) buttons.

After I select a file this function is called based on the changed event

```
$('#selectedFile:file').change(function () {
    var filePath = $('#selectedFile').val();
    var fileName = this.files[0].name;


    $scope.uploadFile({
        'filePath': filePath,
        'fileName': fileName
    });
});
```

This then in turn takes the file name and file path and sends it to an ASP.NET MVC controller function

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult UploadFile(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        //Do some stuff with the file
    }

}
```

But when I want to open the file I get this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not
handled in user code

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'foo' because it is being
used by another process.
```

I guess that the `</file>` is still holding the file so I can't open it in C#.

What do I need to do to "clear" or release the file from the file selector to be able to upload it?

EDIT:

I am also open for any other way which will allow me to get the file path of a selected file.

Answer (score 0):

this is a little late in answering but in hope that it may help others.
I have been dealing with the same exact issue lately.
Here is what I found and works for me.
When you open the file, add these additional attributes to allow you access.

FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read

as in:

```
using (FileStream theStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,